# Information on Salesforce PaaS

Tags: force.com

I have worked on the Salesforce.com Service Cloud and Salesforce.com Sales Cloud, but looking to explore the `PaaS` model i.e. just the force.com layer. I still want to use Salesforce's native capabilities, and utilize Apex, Visualforce.

**Questions:**

1. How do I sign up for a **`test PaaS org with force.com licenses`**? And
   where can I get more information about this?
2. Also, if someone could direct me to find a detailed information on the price breakdown for `Service Cloud license vs. force.com` that
   would be great. How do I figure this out on my own without involving
   **Salesforce** folks?

I look forward to hear back.

Comment: Questions are best posed with one explicit query.  This would be better broken into two questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. The easiest way to provision force.com-licensed orgs is by [signing up to Partnerforce](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/join/), via which you can provision a number of different types of orgs, most of which include force.com licenses. Note that there isn't really a practical difference between a "PaaS org" and a "normal" EE CRM/service org - it's a user license difference and force.com licenses can happily coexist in an org with normal sales/service users.
2. As with any pricing, the best/most accurate way is to actually involve Salesforce folks. But force.com licenses are cheaper than normal Sales/Service Cloud licenses - per [this page](http://www.salesforce.com/au/crm/editions-pricing-platform.jsp), list pricing is $10/user/app/month for "basic apps" and $25/user/app/month for "enterprise apps". The basic definition of an app (beyond one custom app definition) is some limited number of Custom Objects (maybe 10, but as with everything Salesforce keeps changing the rules).

Comment: Thanks jkraybill! Maybe I was not so clear in my question, I will make some updates to it. The basic essence is Do ISV's use Sales or Service Cloud too? I am sure not, because some of them replicate the functionality of case management. So, I am assuming they build the functionality  that Salesforce has using force.com licenses but how come 10 custom object limit is not hit for most of the ISV's?